# Set read-only for only 1 table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to set read only for only 1 table in a database. 
I tried the command

```
ALTER TABLE table SET READ ONLY;
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work - [there is no such option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html). You need to revoke the privileges on that table if you want to make it "read only"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How to set it read ONLY for a single table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw an answer, i hope its helpfully

> ```
> REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE
> ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public
> FROM public, <target_role>;
> ```
>
> Possibly add more roles to the list, but do not forget the role
>   public. Possibly add more schemas to the list, but do not forget the
>   schema public.

Comment: This is for all the tables, how to do it for single table?